# How do I create a map from Google Sheet data that's in another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-maps

I'm trying to create a Google [My Map](https://mapsengine.google.com/) based on addresses in a Google Sheet "file". This seems to work OK following [the standard instructions](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?hl=en), except that I can't seem to extract data on anything except the first sheet within that file; it doesn't allow me to select columns from another sheet. The steps I am following are:

- Within my Google Map, select **Add layer**.
- Select **Import**.
- Select my Google Sheet file from **My Drive**.
- I now only see column titles from my first sheet.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this not supported?

Comment: I doubt this is your problem, but it is worth investigating to be sure: the import function will only recognize the first 2000 rows. If your first page happens to have greater than 2000 rows, then it may be that the other pages's columns will not appear as options. See https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024937

Comment: @HunterHogan, thanks for the thought, but no, that's not my problem. All my sheets are much shorter than that.

Answer (score 1):

Google My Maps will only import data from the first, or leftmost, worksheet in a sheets file.

You can still import multiple worksheets. First, import one worksheet and create a map layer. Then reposition the worksheets so the next one is in the leftmost position and import to the next map layer.

Rinse and repeat.

[image: reposition sheet tab position]